# Spark 2 time type from CSV causing exception with take(5)

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I'm very new to both spark and scala, and am trying to load a csv similar to:

```
A,09:33:57.570
B,09:43:02.577
...
```

The only temporal type I see in scala.sql.types is TimestampType, so I am loading the csv with:

```
val schema = StructType(Array( StructField("A", StringType, true), StructField("time", TimestampType, true)))

val table = spark.read.option("header","false").option("inferSchema","false").schema(schema).csv("../table.csv")
```

This seems to work fine until I do `table.show()` or `table.take(5)`, etc, in which case I get the following exception:

```
scala> table.show()
16/10/07 16:32:25 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:124)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
```

Is there a preferred way of having time data stored within spark? I have also tried leaving it as a string and mapping LocalTime.parse() from java.time on each value, but that fails saying that there is no Encoder for the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SQL type which can directly accommodate time data so probably the best you can do is to use `LongType` by parsing with `unix_timestamp`. Read data with

```
 StructField("time", StringType, true)))
```

It should result with a data frame similar to:

```
val df = Seq(("A", "09:33:57.570"), ("B", "09:43:02.577")).toDF("A", "time")
```

define a simple date format:

```
val format = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

and use it for parsing:

```
df.withColumn("seconds", unix_timestamp($"time", format))
```

Unfortunately this is a lossy transformation.

```
+---+------------+-------+
|  A|        time|seconds|
+---+------------+-------+
|  A|09:33:57.570|  30837|
|  B|09:43:02.577|  31382|
+---+------------+-------+
```

so if you want to preserve milliseconds you can use `java.time.LocalTime` as you do and store the result of `toNanoOfDay`.

```
val nanoOfDay = udf((s: String) => 
  java.time.LocalTime.parse(s).toNanoOfDay)

df.withColumn("nanseconds", nanoOfDay($"time"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at JodaTime for date/time manipulation. You can include this in your pom.xml (for Maven)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```