# Spark SQL: parse timestamp without seconds

Tags: json, apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

Some data I don't own comes with a field that's supposed to be a `timestamp`, but sometimes doesn't seem to comply with the ISO 8601 standard.

In my code, I defined a schema and then when Spark SQL parses my json data, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2016-10-07T11:15Z
```

The source data has the following:

```
"transaction_date_time": "2016-10-07T11:15Z"
```

And my schema is defined as such:

```
 val schema = (new StructType)
      .add("transaction_date_time", TimestampType)
```

I believe it's due to the fact that it's missing the seconds. How could I go to correctly parse the timestamp?

edit:
For example, reading the data using

```
spark.read.schema(schema).json(rdd).show()
```

Will trigger the following error

```
16/10/24 13:06:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2016-10-07T11:15Z
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.skip(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:422)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:417)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertObject(JacksonParser.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertRootField(JacksonParser.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/24 13:06:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2016-10-07T11:15Z
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.skip(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:422)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:417)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertObject(JacksonParser.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertRootField(JacksonParser.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/10/24 13:06:27 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 6 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 23, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2016-10-07T11:15Z
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.skip(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:422)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:417)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertObject(JacksonParser.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertRootField(JacksonParser.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2182)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1925)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1924)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2562)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1924)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:486)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)
  ... 54 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2016-10-07T11:15Z
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.skip(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:422)
  at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:417)
  at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(DatatypeConverter.java:327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertObject(JacksonParser.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertField(JacksonParser.scala:182)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$.convertRootField(JacksonParser.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonParser$$anonfun$parseJson$1.apply(JacksonParser.scala:280)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
val schema = (new StructType)
      .add("transaction_date_time", TimestampType)
```

TO

```
val schema = (new StructType)
      .add("transaction_date_time", StringType)
```

and then use `df.withColumn("columnTimeWithOutSec", unix_timestamp($"time", format))`

```
where format = "format time with out seconds ex HH:mm "
```

just like [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926031/647053)

Also, have a look at [DateTimeUtils.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala) to be inline with Spark style conversions of Date and TimeStamp.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `apache.spark.Timestamp` is just a wrapper for `java.sql.Timestamp`. At least that's what [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.html) leads me to believe.

Accordingly, we can parse a date using `SimpleDateFormat` and extract the milliseconds, passing that to the `Timestamp` constructor.

You could do something like in this example to preprocess the data:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamp = "2016-10-07T11:15Z";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX");
        Date parsedDate = null;
        try{
                parsedDate = df.parse(timestamp);
        }catch(Exception e){
                //do nothing
        }
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(parsedDate);
        System.out.println(ts);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Fri Oct 07 04:15:00 PDT 2016
2016-10-07 04:15:00.0
```

I searched a bit for 'optional parts in a date format' and found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897288/optional-parts-in-simpledateformat) saying you should just make two `SimpleDateFormat`s.

Comment: I don't think it'll be hard to parse that date, even using Java 8 Time API this does it out of the box. The issue lies in Spark I guess, and the challenge is to use your code alongside the code above (I just made edits to explain better)

Comment: I looked around in the docs and found the [encoder trait](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$). I think you need to define a customer `encoder` and use it in lieu of `TimeStamp`. [Here's another link that looks more useful](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-Encoder.html). Still poking around but thought I'd post what I found

Comment: looks like if you simply extend [dataType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.html) you can pass it into the same `add` function you're already using from [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html)